# Increase number of mappers when reading from ORC

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

Here is the problem.

I'm trying to read data from compressed ORC table in Hive, but YARN can't determine correct amount of mappers since it uses value of compressed data size for calculation not original. And that's a problem because we have only 18 mappers for about 100 GB dataset.

Playing around with  hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer helps for increasing number of reducers. Is there any way to obtain more mappers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you play around with the following config settings

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=100000;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=100000;
```

if you reduce the maximum you should get more mappers. I think that should work anyway!